# Google Analytics: How to track when visitors order a brochure?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I implemented Google Analytics on every page of one of my companies website, and on one page there is a simple form to order a free brochure. The main goal of the site is to have my visitors who are potential new customers, order this brochure.

Is there any way I can track who orders a brochure and who doesn't? I want it to be advanced enough so that I can see on which adword-keywords people ordered a brochure on so I can adjust my budget accordingly as to what is effective and what is not.

Seeing the traffic and all is great but I want to make my adword investments more effective, since at the moment I have no clue who is actually ordering a brochure and who is not :)

I am EXTEMELY new to analytics so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to do a few things:

1. Link your analytics and adwords accounts, and turn on auto tagging. This will allow you to get the most information from AdWords to your Analytics account.
2. If the user is sent to a "thank you" page, or any page that is only accessible once a brochure order has been placed, you can simply create a custom report and/or advanced segment to give you the information you want based on the URL. If your user is NOT sent to a unique "thank you" page, you can assign a custom variable to that page that only gets sent after ordering, you can create an event that triggers once an order is complete, you can add a query string parameter to the redirect and filter your data by that, etc.

There are plenty of ways to do it, it just depends on how the website is set up. Here are some links that will point you in the right direction based on what you decide to do. I suggest reading through all of them to get a firm grasp of how Analytics tracks.

Event Tracking: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

Custom Variables: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html

Linking AdWords and Analytics: http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55507

Advanced Segments: http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=108039

Custom Reports: http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=98527

Comment: Thanks! I read up on all the links, set up my "Goal" on my thank you page and even included the funnel link for additional information. I linked the 2 accounts and setup data sharing between them so everything is working as I want, thanks again :)